# Unordered list objects not showing in modal

Tags: html, jsp, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to design a simple modal in which an unordered list `<ul></ul>` is presented, displaying its included list `<li></li>` items. However, when I run the page, the list items are not shown.

[image]

The modal is just blank. However, when I remove the list and add simple body text, the text is displayed as the list should be.

```
        <div class="modal-body">
            text in this region displays when list is removed
        </div>
```

The code:

```
<div class="modal" id="loginModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
     aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                    <h3 class="modal-title"></h3>
                    <button class="close" type="button" data- 
                     dismiss="modal"
                    aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
            </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu"
                aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the dropdown-menu class on your ul, as I don't see anything that could toggle it. That should solve the problem.

If you want to keep the menu as a dropdown, you should add some element that could toggle it, like a link or a button.

```
<div class=dropdown>    
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Show menu
  </button>
  <!-- Your menu -->
</div>
```

Comment: I see..., but i want to have a drop-down menu for that list in which the user can click & make a decision.

Comment: Then you should add something like a button to toggle it : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#single-button-dropdowns

Your problem is that you have a dropdown menu, but nothing to actually toggle the dropdown.